# Importing packages on Anaconda on Windows won't work if PYTHONPATH is set

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, caffe, pycaffe

I've installed Anaconda 4.1.12 x64 on Windows and, when running python apps on command line, it imports packages as numpy just fine... unless I set the environment variable PYTHONPATH. I want to run Caffe on windows, and thus I need to put the Caffe binding on its path.

My test case is this small test.py file:

```
import numpy as np
print np
```

If I `python test.py` it on the command line, with PYTHONPATH not set, I get this:

```
<module 'numpy' from 'C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyc'>
```

Seems fine. But if I set PYTHONPATH, the output is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import decorators as dec
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\decorators.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import SkipTest
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "C:\caffe-windows\python\caffe\io.py", line 2, in <module>
    import skimage.io
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from .util.dtype import *
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dtype import (img_as_float, img_as_int, img_as_uint, img_as_ubyte,
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 8, in <module>
    dtype_range = {np.bool_: (False, True),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bool_'
```

What am I missing?

Edit: adding feedback for @cco:

While trying to `import skimage.io`:

With PYTHONPATH **not** set:

```
<module 'skimage.io' from 'C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\__init__.pyc'>
```

With PYTHONPATH set:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
  import skimage.io as ski
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
  from .util.dtype import *
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from .dtype import (img_as_float, img_as_int, img_as_uint, img_as_ubyte,
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py", line 2, in <module>
  import numpy as np
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
  from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from .type_check import *
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
  import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  from . import decorators as dec
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\decorators.py", line 21, in <module>
  from .utils import SkipTest
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
  from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
  import io as _io
File "C:\caffe-windows\python\caffe\io.py", line 2, in <module>
  import skimage.io
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
  from ._io import *
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 1, in <module>
  from io import BytesIO
ImportError: cannot import name BytesIO
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in skimage: it's expecting to be able to use `mp.bool_`.  What happens when (without setting PYTHONPATH) you run `import skimage.io`?

Comment: With PYTHONPATH **not** set: `<module 'skimage.io' from 'C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\__init__.pyc'>`

With PYTHONPATH set: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
      `File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>`
        `import skimage.io as ski`
... long track of tears...
      `File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 1, in <module>`
        `from io import BytesIO`
    `ImportError: cannot import name BytesIO`

Comment: What are you setting `PYTHONPATH` to?

Comment: Yes, and without setting it, what do you get by running `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` ?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for trying to help me.
@darthbith: I'm setting it to `C:\caffe-windows\python;C:\caffe-windows\python\caffe`.

Comment: @cco. I had to use `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"`:

`['', 'C:\\caffe-windows\\python', 'C:\\caffe-windows\\python\\caffe', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Anaconda2', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.4.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg']`